# Shopware 6 property type dropdown not hiding un-combinable options

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

For all properties shown in the configuration section of the product details, if something is not considered combinable with the currently selected options they are disabled.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig#L58

However, this doesn't appear to apply to the dropdown select configuration option, it simply shows all options.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator/select.html.twig

Is this intended (undocumented) behaviour of the dropdown property option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you use buttons for selecting a variant. While a button of a property that would lead to an unavailable variant is rendered like it might be disabled, you can nonetheless still click it. It will simply take you to the next available variant with that specific property.

For example a color might not be available in the currently selected size. If the button for the color would actually be disabled, you'd have to change the size first, then check if the color is available in that size and so on. Instead it is more convenient to be able to still click the button for the color and be redirected to the next available size in that color. The styling of the button, which looks like it is disabled to be fair, only conveys that clicking on it will change the size, since the combination of both is not available.

The problem with the select dropdown is that the appearance of their options, unlike the buttons, can't be styled in a sufficient manner. While you can disable options, that in turn will make them not be selectable at all, not allowing for the intended behavior explained above.